# How does a service like Instagram cache images that are frequently viewed

Tags: architecture

A service like instagram that has world wide users probably uses 1000's of CDN's. When a user with say million or more followers uploads x number of pics, how are they cached. Are they PUSHED to all the CDN, or do followers pull the image from say a central distributed storage which then gets cached at CDN's during the process of downloading the file.

SO gave me a warning regarding downvotes, If you want go ahead and downvote but please specify a reason. I couldn't find an answer hence posting it here. If you know the answer please help

Answer (score 0):

They should balance costs (for storage and for transfers) somehow with availability.
It does not make sense to push every file into all locations because there is a possibility that no-one will request some of them ever.
It also does not make sense to keep backup of central storage when you have to distribute them any way.
Most likely they push ALL files to at least one alternative geo location (and datacenter) with minimal transfer fees to have at least one copy of all files to provide high availability but keeping costs down.
It does not make much sense to differentiate popular and unpopular files because only first visitor will get request miss with subsequent pull.
But it is possible that they push files of popular files prior any notification push to avoid bottlenecks with multiple users having miss requests simultaneously.
The rest of the less popular files should be pulled to decrease costs for storage and transfers.

And do not forget about thumbnails.
Some social networks rejected idea of keeping of never requested files in favor of FPGA on-the-fly conversion.